# Cell culture disasosiation

Tags: cell-culture

I am doing to passaging cancer cell ( Dld-1 Cell line). Trypsination was conducted with 0.25 trypsin-edta 1 ml to t-flask 25 in 2 min. Then I add 6 ml complete media (have 10% FBS for inactivated trypsin. Cause queue in sentrifuge, my Cell is at solution for 40 min, this is clear for my Cell? How long cancer cell can survive in trypsin and complete media (1:6) solution in room temperature (not incubated).